# Change name form SF3

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I searched to change the name of the fields input of form generated by SF3, but doesn't seem to work.

I currently have 2 forms on a template (register/connection) and when I'm submitting 1 of both, the both are submitted.

I've read that we can handle the form by the name, but the forms of the same name "form", and I can't change this, I're read the doc on SF site, but something seem to be wrong.

Here's the code of 1 (the second one is similar)

```
<?php 
use AppBundle\Entity\Connection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

public function getFormConnectionAction( Request $request ) {
        $connection = new Connection();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder( $connection )
                     ->setAttribute( 'name', 'connection' )
                     ->add( 'pseudo', TextType::class )
                     ->add( 'password', PasswordType::class )
                     ->add( 'send_connection_form', SubmitType::class, array( 'label' => 'Se connecter', ) )
                     ->getForm();

        //Keep the original clean
        $formCloned = clone $form;

        //Handling the request of submit
        $formCloned->handleRequest( $request );

        if ( $formCloned->isSubmitted() && $formCloned->isValid() ) {
            dump( $form->getName() ); //returning name form
        }

        return $this->render( 'forms/connection.html.twig', array( 'form' => $form->createView() ) );
    }
```

Any idea ? Keeping to seek, but seriously I don't see my mistake !

Comment: Set form action (eg in controller): `$form->setAction($this->generateUrl('target_route'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally find the solution for it, maybe not the better one (if you can comment about it)

Here we are, I juste defined some "FormType" like this :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Connection;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ConnectionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {
        $builder
            ->add( 'pseudo', TextType::class )
            ->add( 'password', PasswordType::class )
            ->add( 'send_connection_form', SubmitType::class, array( 'label' => 'Se connecter', ) );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'connection_form';
    }

    public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver ) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Connection::class //My entity for the DB
        ]);
    }
}
```

I call it by this in my Controller :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\ConnectionFormType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class ConnectionController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Get the form connection over all the controllers
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface
     */
    public function getFormConnectionAction( Request $request ) {
        $form = $this->createForm(ConnectionFormType::class);

        //Keep the original clean
        $formCloned = clone $form;

        //Handling the request of submit
        //$formCloned->handleRequest( $request );
        if($request->isMethod('POST') && $request->request->has('connection_form'))
        {
            $formCloned->submit($request->request->get('connection_form'));
        }

        if ( $formCloned->isSubmitted() && $formCloned->isValid() ) {
            //dump( $formCloned->all()); //returning name
        }

        return $this->render( 'forms/connection.html.twig', array( 'form' => $form->createView() ) );
    }

}
```

Any comment about this ? Is it good ? Could be improved ? Anything else ?

Comment: Yes, this is the standard way to do this (probably could be a method in the form builder for add the name of the form but i don't know). Take care that the method getName is deprecated and will be removed in the sf3 version so take care of [this migration guide](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form)

Comment: If you are going to use the form more then once then preferable way is to write a separate form class and call this in the controller.

Comment: Even if you are not going to use a form twice, better to create a form class. Less code in the action = more readability and separation of logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answers !